# Get places count of my friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want likes count, wall post count and places count of all my friends.

```
SELECT name ,likes_count, wall_count FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

This returning me list of all of my friends names with their total page likes count and wall post count
but i also need places count of all friends. I think facebook provide it directly like likes and wall post. As in profile we can see total places count just like likes count and friend count and mutual friends count. I have also tried this.

```
SELECT author_uid, checkin_id FROM checkin WHERE author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) OR tagged_uids IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) LIMIT 5000
```

My idea was that i will get it and process it on my application end but it is not returning full list of checkins. How can i get all checkins of my friends with their ids so than i can calculate their total checkins ???
OR if there is a direct way of getting places count then it will be much efficient for my code ...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use any `LIMIT`.

```
SELECT author_uid, checkin_id 
  FROM checkin 
 WHERE author_uid IN (
       SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
    OR tagged_uids IN (
       SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

This works and gives me 737 checkins for all my friends. FQL doesn't have a `COUNT` function like in SQL, so you will have to enumerate checkins in the language of your choice.

Comment: this returning me only list of 153 checkins, but i know i have much more then that

Comment: I think it really does return the whole list. Are you sure you don't confond a *checkin* with *a post with a location attached*? Read the warning [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin). So make sure you know what you mean by Checkin.